# How to interrupt `sleep` in terminal on macOS?

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, interrupt, iterm2

I am executing `sleep 10 && echo hello` command on iTerm2.

I want to interrupt this command without waiting 10 seconds to print the word `hello` to the terminal. I have tried the key binding such as Command + C but it doesn't work.

What is the key binding for interrupting long running command such as `sleep`?

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl`+`C`?

Comment: That's strange. It works for me using zsh on iTerm2

Comment: yes I did. Command+C is basically the same.  @Simone

Comment: yes on my pc ```CTRL+C``` works fine but on mac I haven't find any key bindings for that @Simone

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, too, you need to press <kbd>^Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (***NOT*** <kbd>⌘Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>⚠️) to interrupt a process in the shell.

Alternatively, in macOS's Terminal app (but not in iTerm), you can press <kbd>⌘Command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> and it will be passed to the shell as the interrupt signal (`^C`).

(However, note that, if `sleep 10` gets interrupted, `echo hello` will *not* get executed.)

Comment: I have tried all solutions. But still doesn't work. I thinks there is issue with key bindings.  @Marlon Richert

Comment: Control-C should always work. It’s not possible to override it in the shell. Have you tried using macOS’s Terminal app instead of iTerm?

Comment: Yes I tried terminal but still not working @Marlon Richert